# How to center the title of an appbar

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to center the title text in an app bar that has both a leading and trailing actions.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final menuButton = new PopupMenuButton<int>(
    onSelected: (int i) {},
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx) {},
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.dashboard,
    ),
  );

  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that
      // was created by the App.build method, and use it to set
      // our appbar title.
      title: new Text(widget.title, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility),
          onPressed: () {},
      ),
      actions: [
        menuButton,
      ],
    ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new Text(
        'Button tapped $_counter time${ _counter == 1 ? '' : 's' }.',
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _incrementCounter,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: new Icon(Icons.add),
    ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
  );
}
```

This works well except the title is aligned on the left as is shown in this picture:

[image: TITLE TO THE LEFT]

As I try to include the title in the center, it appears that it's too much to the left:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final menuButton = new PopupMenuButton<int>(
    onSelected: (int i) {},
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx) {},
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.dashboard,
    ),
  );

  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that
      // was created by the App.build method, and use it to set
      // our appbar title.
      title: new Center(child: new Text(widget.title, textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility),
          onPressed: () {},
      ),
      actions: [
        menuButton,
      ],
    ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new Text(
        'Button tapped $_counter time${ _counter == 1 ? '' : 's' }.',
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _incrementCounter,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: new Icon(Icons.add),
    ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
  );
}
```

[image: TITLE NOT WELL CENTERED]

I would love a solution to get the title text centered perfectly between the 2 icons.

Answer (score 590, accepted):

Centering the title is the default on iOS. On Android, the `AppBar`'s title defaults to left-aligned, but you can override it by passing [`centerTitle: true`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/centerTitle.html) as an argument to the `AppBar` constructor.

Example:

```
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true, // this is all you need
  ...
)
```

Comment: in this case title appears not exactly at the center :/

Comment: This doesn't even affect the alignment of the title for me.

Comment: @MichaelTolsma, you should remove any Center widget-like in the title property if you want it to be applied.

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem and it finally worked when I added the
**mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min** to my `Row()` widget:

```
 return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that
        // was created by the App.build method, and use it to set
        // our appbar title.
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              widget.title,
            ),
          ],
        ),

        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: [
          menuButton,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 20):

In my case I wanted to have a logo / image centered instead of a text. In this case, `centerTitle` is not enough (not sure why, I have an svg file, maybe that's the reason... ), so for example, this:

```
appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: AppImages.logoSvg)
```

will not really center the image (plus the image can be too big, etc.). What works well for me is a code like this:

```
appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true,
    title: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 35, maxWidth: 200),
        child: AppImages.logoSvg)),
```

Comment: The accepted answer works for Text but this is the right answer for custom Widgets. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me! It seems that centerTitle not work properly when there are actions on the toolbar. This one fixed it.

Comment: Has no other effect for me than the more simple solution. In my case, having transparent border space around the image lead to incorrect placement. Simply cutting the image a bit tighter made the simple solution work.

Answer (score 14):

You can just use the `centerTitle` property in the `appBar` section to center your title
using:

```
centerTitle: true
```

Comment: Simple Spell but quite unbreakable

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I make centerTitle on my appbar:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    centerTitle: true ,
    title: new Text("Login"),
  ),
  body: new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
      key: formkey,
        child: ListView(
        children: buildInputs() + buildSubmitButton(),
      ),
   ) 
);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
appbar:AppBar(
centerTitle: true,
title:Text("HELLO")
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a different approach if you want to create a custom app bar title. For example you want an image and a text at the center of app bar then add

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.your_app_icon,
                color: Colors.green[500],
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Text('YourAppTitle'))
            ],

          ),
  )
```

Here we have created a `Row` with `MainAxisAlignment.center` to center the children. Then we have added two children - An Icon and a `Container` with text. I wrapped `Text` widget in the `Container` to add the necessary padding.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code:

```
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  …
),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can center the title of an appBar by using **centerTitle** parameter.

**centerTitle** is Boolean Datatype, and default value is False.

**centerTitle** : ***true***

Example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('App Title'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

appBar has its own bool condition for title center show or not,

[image]

so,
if you set true,

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      "header Text",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
```

then it will be centre,other then its default left align (in android)
ios set center(in default).

Answer (score 4):

Yeah but in my case i used centertitle as well as axis alignment then it made it centre , if i am using only onw of it then it is is not making it centre , here is how i am doing it :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:infintywalls/widgets/widget.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            appName(),
          ],
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and yeah btw appName() is my custom widget not a default builtin one.

home this is helpful to you
thanks

Comment: you don't need an extra Row() widget for doing this, you will only need to set centerTitle as true

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by using Center class.

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: const Center(
    child: Text("I Am Rich"),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying many solutions this helped me `centerTitle: true` 
adding sample code in addition to *@Collin Jackson* answer

**Example**
in `build(BuildContext context)`

do this

```
appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),centerTitle: true
      ),
```

Comment: It's been a while, this did solve the issue.  Very simple.  
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Title'),
            actions: <Widget> [
               IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.file_upload), onPressed: _pressed),
            ],
            leading: IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: _pressed),
            centerTitle: true,
        )
        body: Text("Content"),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help in making Appbar Title Text in Center.
You can choose to add your desired Styles using Style or comment it if not needed.

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title:  const Center(
            child: Text(
              "App Title",
              style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

On App Display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It my case this code works:-

appBar: AppBar(

```
    centerTitle: true,

    elevation: 2,

    title: Center(

      child: Row(

        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

        children: [

          Container(

            child: Text("  TINKLE"),

          )

        ],

      ),

    ),
    
  ),
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

AppBar(
centerTitle: true, // this is all you need
...
)
it is OK with me,, using:centerTitle: true

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SliverAppBar and FlexibleSpaceBar widgets, you can use like this. This worked for me especially fixes the problem in android in last version of flutter sdk. These title padding and center tile, both worked in expanded and collapsed mode.

```
FlexibleSpaceBar(
centerTitle: true,
titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10),
title: _buildHeader(imagePath, strTitle, context),
background: Container(),)
```

Comment: Why is this happening? I just updated Flutter SDK to 3.19 and my title within the flexible space bar was not centered anymore... my tabs were also misplaced.

Comment: It is android problem. I also fixed this with center true. But still has some problem

Answer (score -3):

Use `Center` object

```
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Center(
        child: const Text('Title Centered')
      )
    )
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because it is not supposed to be like that.