# Centering in the AppBar with the back button

Tags: flutter, dart, button, position, appbar

I store in the title the text and icon that are displayed in the AppBar in the center. During the transition, the back button that appears takes up part of the line and my centering shifts.  Can I somehow get around this and make the titled centered even if there is a back button ?

[image]

The bottom icon is located in the center of the screen

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: BackButton(
        color: Colors.grey
   ), 
          elevation: 0,
          title: Center(
              child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.telegram_sharp, color: iconColor),
              Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2, vertical: 2)),
              Text('ID', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18)),
            ],
          ))),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            _MainInfoWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center the title of an appbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981406/how-to-center-the-title-of-an-appbar)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh No, only doing `centerTitle: true` in this case won't solve the problem. See my below answer. You can retract your close vote.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Correct, my bad, I didn't look at _all_ the other answers. I have casted a vote to close this question.

Comment: It is ok I think, while it is easier to answer rather than finding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the following properties on the `Row()`:

```dart
MainAxisAlignment.center
MainAxisSize.min
```

And:
`centerTitle: true`
On the `appBar()`.
Also, remove your `Center()` widget.

Complete example:

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: BackButton(color: Colors.grey),
          elevation: 0,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.telegram_sharp, color: Colors.black),
              Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2, vertical: 2)),
              Text('ID', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18)),
            ],
          )),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
AppBar(
centerTitle: true
```

And

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```

Or if that's not helped

When the transition occurs, change

```
mainAxiAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start otherwise center
```

Comment: Row -> mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min

Comment: Updated now. Check