# SliverAppBar center title horizontally

Tags: flutter

I want to center the title of `SliverAppBar` horizontally. But it's not centered. How can I fix this without using FlexibleSpaceBar title?

Also is there a way to stop FlexibleSpaceBar overlapping and covering the app bar content when scrolled up?

```
 SliverAppBar(
  pinned: true,
  expandedHeight: 255,
  actions: const [CoinCount()],
  title: Center(child: Text(_getVsText())),
  titleSpacing: 0,
  elevation: 0,
  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
    background: Column(children: [
      const SizedBox(
        height: 40,
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center the title of an appbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981406/how-to-center-the-title-of-an-appbar)

Comment: `SliverAppBar` has `centerTitle` property just like `AppBar`

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

You can just use the `centerTitle` property in the SliverAppBar section to center your title using:

Example:

```
  SliverAppBar(
  pinned: true,
  centerTitle: true, //   <<---- add this line
  expandedHeight: 255,
  actions: const [CoinCount()],
  title: Center(child: Text(_getVsText())),
  titleSpacing: 0,
  elevation: 0,
  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
    background: Column(children: [
      const SizedBox(
        height: 40,
      ),
```

Happy Coding ‍‍.

Comment: thanks. that works thanks, any idea how to stop FlexibleSpaceBar from going up and overlapping the appbar when scrolling up? I can mark this as the answer.